# Laravel: Show n last lines of log file from Controller

Tags: laravel

How to show the n last lines of a log file from a controller ?

I'm currently showing the whole file this way:

```
public function showLogs()
{
    $filePath = storage_path("logs/custom.log");
    return File::get($filePath);
}
```

Like I would do with:

```
tail -30 storage/logs/custom.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [escapeshellarg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) function here for security reason

```
$file = escapeshellarg(storage_path("logs/custom.log")); 
$line = `tail -n 30 $file`;

dd($line);
```